# GGPLOT stacked bars order

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
big_theme <- theme(
  panel.background=element_rect(fill = "black"),
  plot.background =element_rect(fill = "black", colour = NA),
  plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, size=15, color="white"),
  axis.text.y=element_text(colour="white", size=14),
  axis.title.x = element_text(colour = "white", size=14),
  axis.title.y = element_text(colour = "white", size=14),
  axis.text.x=element_text(vjust=1, angle=45, color="white", size=14, hjust=1),
  strip.background =element_rect(fill="black"),
  strip.text = element_text(colour = 'white'),
  strip.text.y = element_text(angle=0), 
  legend.position = "top"
)

theme2 = theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'black'),
  legend.background=element_rect(fill="black"),
  legend.text = element_text(colour="white", size=14), 
  legend.justification = "right",
  legend.key.height = unit(1, "line"),
  legend.key = element_rect(color="black", fill="black"))

theme3 = theme(plot.background = element_rect(fill = 'black'))

plot1 <- ggplot(sample_data) + big_theme + theme2 + theme3
plot1 + geom_col(aes(x=category, y=value, fill=variable, color=variable)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#000000", "#D3667C", "#53AC79")) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#00A2EF", "#D3667C", "#53AC79"))
```

I have a dataset that looks like:

```
category    variable    value
a   x   1.2
b   x   1.05
c   x   1.11
a   y   1.43
b   y   1.09
c   y   0.97
a   z   1.12
b   z   1.46
c   z   1.32
```

I want the order in the ggplot of the bars and legend to be z, x, y. Im trying to use an order variable to do that but it doesn't work when I use order inside my aesthetics. So the bar for a is unfilled and b and c are unfilled.

Comment: I don't see any attempt to change variable's order in your code. Try running `sample_data$variable = factor(sample_data$variable, levels = c("z", "x", "y"))` or something to that effect before plotting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your can relevel `variable` to `c("z", "x", "y")`：

```
plot1 + geom_col(aes(x=category,y=value,
  fill=forcats::fct_relevel(variable, c("z", "x", "y")),
  color=forcats::fct_relevel(variable, c("z", "x", "y")))) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("#000000","#D3667C","#53AC79")) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("#00A2EF","#D3667C","#53AC79"))
```

Hoping this helps.